# Sequelize Promises not working after node update from v12 to v16

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Promises are stopped working after updated the node version from 12 to 16. Debug console execution stops without showing errors. Also enabled the node --trace-warnings.

WWW.js
var db = require('../models');

```
            function runPortal() {
              db.sequelize.sync().then(function () {
                modelSync.start(db, function (err) { 
                   //some code here
                   console.log('Server is listening on port');
                });
              }).catch(function (err) {
                   console.log(err);
              });
            }

model.js

if(!global.hasOwnProperty('db')){
    var fs = require('fs');
    var path = require('path');
    var sync = require('./sync');
    var Sequelize = require('sequelize'),
        sequelize = null;
        process.env.DATABASE_URL =  'postgres://url'; //Online DB url
    if(process.env.DATABASE_URL){
        sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL,{dialect: 'postgres',
        dialectOptions: {
          ssl: true
        }
    });   
    }else{
        var db = global.config.db;
        sequelize = new Sequelize(db.dbname,db.username,db.password,{
            host: 'localhost',
            dialect: 'postgres',
             logging: false,
            pool:{max: 5, min: 0, idle: 10000}
        });
    }
    
    var db = {};
    fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
        .filter(function(file){
            return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== "index.js") && (file !== "sync");
        })
        .forEach(function(file){
            var model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
            db[model.name] = model;
        });
    
    Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
        if ("associate" in db[modelName]) {
            db[modelName].associate(db);
        }
    });
    
    //sync.start(db);
    
    db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
    db.sequelize = sequelize;
    
    global.db = db;
}

module.exports = global.db;
```

App Versions:-
--Angular CLI: 11.1.2
--Node: 16.15.1
--npm: 8.12.2

Comment: Does the service stop after such errors?

Comment: Further Execution stops and there is no error. Same thing is working in node 12v but not 16v.